# ajax loading message in jquery dialog box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a scenario where a dialog box is getting opened with form data and a submit button.When I click on this submit button I need to show an overlay ajax loading image with some message saying "Please wait... Data is being updated". Once data got updated (success message from server) I need to show another overlay ajax loading image with some other message saying "Your Data has been updated sucessfuly.". In case of error response from server I need to show overlay ajax loading image with some error message saying "There is some problem while trying to update data".

## Below is the code that I am using to show the dialog box and to update data in server.

```
$("#popup").dialog({ 
    autoOpen: false,
    title : "View/Edit Screen",             
    dialogClass : "pop-content pop-header-colr pop-button pop-float",
    width:750,
    height:650,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    show: 'clip',
    buttons:{
        'SUBMIT':function(){
            if($('#pop_up_form').valid()){                          
                $.ajax({
                    url:'a_url_path',
                    type:'GET',
                    data:{
                       formData:JSON.stringify(ConvertFormToJSON('#pop_up_form')),
                       bkup_doc_path:$('#bkup_doc_proof').val(),
                       lttr_doc_path:$('#lttr_doc').val()   
                    },                              
                    success: function(data){
                       alert("success");    
                    },
                    error:function(xhr,textStatus,errorThrown){
                        alert(errorThrown); 
                    }
                })  
            }
            else {

            }
        }   
    }
});
```

Any one have any idea about how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
buttons:{
    'SUBMIT':function(){
        if($('#pop_up_form').valid()){                          

           $('.new-dialog')

            $.ajax({
                url:'a_url_path',
                type:'GET',
                 ....
```

Where I type $('.new-dialog') you should create a new dialog box with background of a gif ('ajax loader' everywhere in google), it would be more useful when you changes his css and make the z-index bigger than the other dialog. And of course close it when you have an answer! Or maybe only change the text inside and remove the background loading..

The same way if the answer if success or error, changing the message.

Comment: thanks for your response.I dont need to close the new-dialob box manually. It should close automatically once the request got over.